# get canvas mouse position on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, mouse

** **Read before you mark as duplicate!** **

Getting the mouse position on the canvas nearly works fine.

My window size is `800 x 600`

My canvas size is `400 x 300`:

```
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 300;
```

My canvas `css` size is `100% x 100%`:

```
canvas {width: 100vw; height: 100vh;}
```

The problem is: if my mouse is in the middle of the canvas I get this mouse position: `400, 300`. If my window size was `1600 x 1200` I would get `800, 600`.

I would like to get the **canvas** position of the mouse. What I mean by this, is I'm looking to get `200, 150`, regardless of the window size.

How would I do this?
Thank's for the help.

Comment: your canvas size is NOT 400x300, since you defined it as 100vw/100vh. so you're getting exactly what you asked for. the position on the canvas in the size the canvas is displayed as. if you want to convert that to your 400x300 hardcoded values, you'll have do the math yourself. `actual X = (displayed X / hardcoded X) * Xpos`

Comment: The `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` are 400 and 300, but the `css` is **stretching** it to 100vw/10vh like I want. I could do the math my self but maybe there is an easier and quicker built-in way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create conversion from model coordinates to screen coordinates and back. Here is good explanation for it: http://www.ckollars.org/canvas-two-coordinate-scales.html

Comment: Great thanks! I wish there was a built-in function like `ctx.toModelX(x)` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You could paste this into your code.

```
document.getElementById("canvasId").addEventListener('mousemove',function(event){mousePos(event);});
function getMousePos(e){
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    //this gets your canvas size.
    return {
        x: Math.round(e.clientX - rect.left),
        y: Math.round(e.clientY - rect.top)
    };
function mousePos(e){
    var pos = getMousePos(e);
    var mouseX = pos.x;
    var mouseY = pos.y;
}
```

then you could just reference the mouseX and mouseY somewhere else.

```
//enter the rest of your code here.
```